# HP Office Jet Pro 8610 Printer Issue - Defective Cartridge Error

Tags: printer, hardware-failure, hp, cartridge

I'm facing an issue with my HP Office Jet Pro 8610 printer, specifically related to a "defective cartridge" error. The printer indicates that at least one cartridge, presumably the black one, is faulty, preventing printing. However, when I enter the MFG mode (holding down the power button until the LED on the left front lights up, then pressing 1x Home, 1x Return, 2x Home, selecting MFG, letting it run for 5 minutes, and finally pressing the power button once), the printer works fine, albeit being recognized (by linux) as an HP 8500.

Upon restarting the printer in normal mode, the problem persists.

Why does the printer work in MFG mode, but not in normal mode?

How can I get the printer work in normal mode?

I am using original and new HP cartridges (950/951 XL). I also tried to clean the contacts of the cartridges and of the printer head with Isopropyl alcohol.

Here is the error message:

[image]

[image]

The problem occurred after replacing the black cartridge with a new one. Not after a firmware upgrade. The firmware version is FDP1CN2022AR FW-Patch-Version:0

**Edit:**
I just changed the black cartridge for another new one. Same problem. I noticed that in both cases in MFG mode the black cartridge indicates only 1/4 full ink level. Maybe this gives an indication of how to solve the problem.

If I don't manage to solve the problem: Is it ok just to use MFG mode for printing on a regular basis?

Comment: If truly an HP8500, it has print heads in addition to ink cartridges.  If the print heads need to be replaced, they cost more than a new printer.  If HP 8500, replace it. My own HP8610 (no print heads) is still going strong.

Comment: A number of HP printer firmware updates have been *designed* to disable the printer with non-OEM products: https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2024/01/hp-sued-again-for-blocking-third-party-ink-from-printers-accused-of-monopoly/ . This could be a side-effect of such an update.